# Nx cloud build is tagged with "no branch"

Tags: continuous-integration, nrwl-nx, render.com

I'm using render.com to build a NX project and all builds are tagged with "no branch" in NX cloud. How do I get the branch to show up in Nx cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set `NX_BRANCH` on CI platforms they don't directly support. For render.com, it would be:

`NX_BRANCH=$RENDER_GIT_BRANCH npx nx build ...`